# Does zero polynomial $P(x)=0$ whose coefficients are all zero has any roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

The degree of the zero polynomial is undefined, but many authors conventionally set it equal to $-1$ or $-\infty$.

I read the above in Wolframmathworld I wonder whether the zero polynomial has any roots?

Comment: Yes, every element is a root of the zero polynomial.

Comment: Yes you can take any element it would a root of the zero polynomial

Comment: @DonThousand If every element is a root then why do some author conventionally set the degree of the zero polynomial as $-1$ instead of  $-\infty$ (because if a polynomial has $n$ roots then the degree should be at least $n$)

Comment: @Asher2211 Different conventions. $-1$ is a more useful choice of degree for $0$ in some contexts. Same reason why we define $0^0$ differently depending on what's convenient in the given context.

Comment: @DonThousand Seems to me that $\deg(pq)=\deg(p)+\deg(q)$ is a good reason for defining $\deg(0)=-\infty$. What's a similar reason for saying $-1$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If you want the relation "the degree of $f$ is the smallest $i$ such that $f^{(i+1)}$ is the zero polynomial" to hold for all polynomials, it would make sense to set the degree of the zero polynomial to $-1$.